# Date format MMM dd yyyy, hh:mm a

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to present a Date inside ng-grid, I wrote a filter either the date is Expired or not, if so present a text otherwise a Date format `MMM dd yyyy, hh:mm a`

```
.filter("expiredDate", Filter);

function Filter($filter) {
    return function (val) {
        if (val === 'Expired')
            return val;
        var res = $filter('date')(val, 'MMM dd yyyy, hh:mm a');
        return res;
    }
}
```

This displays "/Date(1495366770000)/" instead of the Date and this is the value of val

Comment: Why don't you just use momentjs to work with dates?

Comment: Performance issues